# Using python to read a file and write the content to the end of a URL

Tags: python, json, api

I'm trying to use python to append a set of stored words to an API url. The URL remains the same throughout, with exception of the stored words. As of right now, the code is:

```
import requests
import json

with open("words.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        f=line.rstrip("\t")

url = '[url here]'+f    
result=requests.get(url)
result.status_code
result.text
result.json()
print (result.json())
```

The code functions as it should for the first line in the text file, but after that does not continue to scan the text file for the words on lines 2+.

My goal for this project is to have each word go through the process sequentially and print the results given by the API results. I would like to write them to a file as well, but that's another issue I'm going to figure out on my own. This is my first python project so I'm a bit unsure of how to fix this issue, and none of the searching I've done on YouTube is very helpful since this is a rather specific issue as it relates to adding things to urls. I think I'm missing something small, but it's driving me crazy trying to figure out what.

Any help would be extremely appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```py
import requests
import json

with open("words.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        param = line.rstrip("\t")
        
        url = '[url here]'+f    
        result = requests.get(url)
        
        print(result.json())
```

explanation:

The reason you only returned the request for one line is because the request was made after the loop had finished. `f` only had one value, and the request was performed on that.

Also, I don't know why you would call `readlines()` inside the for loop; it should be called prior and is what should be looped over.

Hope this helped :D

Answer (score 0):

As I understood from your question and sample code. You are modifying `f` in line `f=line.rstrip("\t")` while looping through `f`. This is an issue. Another issue is, you don't loop through `f`, while using `readlines()`. What you should do is:

```
with open('words.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in f:
        # Inside this for loop, do what you wanted to do with each line after reading it.
        # Example: `url = '[url here]'+line` and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests

url = 'https://example.com'
with open('words.txt', 'r') as f:
    urls = [f'{url}/{line.strip()}' for line in f]
print(urls)

for url in urls:
    res = requests.get(url)
    print(res.json())
```

Comment: Kindly add a line or two to explain what you are doing. This will help the readers to understand the answer more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests

URL = "http://foo.bar"

with open("words.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip()
        url = f"{URL}/{line}"
        print(url) # you don't need this, but adding this for output as an example
        result = requests.get(url)
        print(result.json())
```

A few things you can change here to make this more concise. Given that you'll have a constant base URL, define it at the top of the file in all uppercase(abide by PEP-8). This snippet opens the file for reading, collects the lines in the file in an iterable list in `lines = f.readlines()`. Once collected, you can iterate through this list with the `for` loop. Performing the action needed on each individual item in the file. F-strings are typically better practice than concatenating with `+`.

If you have a `words.txt` file containing:

```
foo
bar
is
great
```

then the output of the above snippet would be:

```
python scratch.py 
http://foo.bar/foo
http://foo.bar/bar
http://foo.bar/is
http://foo.bar/great
```

Answer (score 0):

you only loop through the input, but the requests is outside the loop. So you only request one, all you need todo is add identation begining from `url=` so the rest of code included in the loop